# What is the big O of the real fast Fourier transform

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, fourier-transform, numerical-calculus

as is well known, the 1D Fast Fourier Transform requires $\mathcal{O}\left(N\log_2N\right)$ computations. And is also known that in the case that the input is real, the Hermitian symmetry can be used and we only need to compute half of the spectrum.

My question is, in the real fast Fourier transform we can claim that the complexity of the algorithm is given by $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{N}{2}\log_2\left(\frac{N}{2}\right)\right)$?

I'm searching for this answer in some books of Fourier transforms but couldn't find any answer.

Thank you,
Tiago

Comment: For big Oh notation these constant factors don't change anything. You could do a full count of real arithmetic operations if you want I guess.

Comment: Hm.. I know that the constant factors in big O notation don't change anything, but I thought that was applied in cases like $\mathcal{O}(N+3)$

Comment: That $+3$ is a lower order term, not a constant factor, which also doesn't count. The outer $N/2$ in your notation is a constant factor, not a lower order term.